# MainPage of XAML is not loading Designer

Tags: app.xaml

when I click Mainpage.xaml I get this problem:

> Designer could not be started because of a permissions issue on the
>   drive to which it is installed. Please check the permissions of the
>   folder before trying to start the designer.

Can anyone give solution for that using snapshots?

Answer (score 1):

you can look at [this post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/388dd1c5-ca01-4538-baa8-7555100e4f80/visual-studio-12-designer-could-not-be-started-because-of-a-permissions-issue?forum=vseditor) for answer.

You can also try to run Visual Studio as Administrator ansd when it asks for permission to run the designer click ok and wait.

hope it helped.